# Find Most Relevant Child in Dictionary

Tags: python, categories

Taking this dictionary:

```
{'local': {'count': 7,
    'dining-and-nightlife': {'count': 1,
        'bar-clubs': {'count': 1}
    },
    'activities-events': {'count': 6,
        'outdoor-adventures': {'count': 4},
        'life-skill-classes': {'count': 2}
    }
}}
```

How do I determine the most relevant match (within a 30% leeway)? For example, activities-events has a count of 6 so 6/7 = 85% and its child outdoor-adventures has a count of 4 out 6 (66%). So from this the most relevant category is outdoor-adventures.

In this example:

```
{'local': {'count': 11,
    'dining-and-nightlife': {'count': 4,
        'bar-clubs': {'count': 4}
    },
    'activities-events': {'count': 6,
        'outdoor-adventures': {'count': 4},
        'life-skill-classes': {'count': 2}
    }
}}
```

Take both dining-and-nightlife (33%) with bar-clubs (100%) and activities-events (54%) with
 outdoor-aventures (66%).

I was hoping the percentage cutoff to be determined by

```
cutoff = 0.3
```

The idea here is to determine which category is most relevant removing the smaller results (below a 30%) match.

@F.J answered this question below but now I wish to update the counts in the tree.

Inital Output:

```
{'local': {'activities-events': {'count': 6,
                             'life-skill-classes': {'count': 2},
                             'outdoor-adventures': {'count': 4}},
       'count': 11,
       'dining-and-nightlife': {'bar-clubs': {'count': 4}, 'count': 4}}}
```

Post output:

```
{'local': {'activities-events': {'count': 6,
                             'life-skill-classes': {'count': 2},
                             'outdoor-adventures': {'count': 4}},
       'count': 10,
       'dining-and-nightlife': {'bar-clubs': {'count': 4}, 'count': 4}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, note that this will modify your input dictionary in place:

```
def keep_most_relevant(d, cutoff=0.3):
    for k, v in list(d.items()):
        if k == 'count':
            continue
        if 'count' in d and v['count'] < d['count'] * cutoff:
            del d[k]
        else:
            keep_most_relevant(v)
```

Examples:

```
>>> d1 = {'local': {'count': 7, 'dining-and-nightlife': {'count': 1, 'bar-clubs': {'count': 1}}, 'activities-events': {'count': 6, 'outdoor-adventures': {'count': 4}, 'life-skill-classes': {'count': 2}}}}
>>> keep_most_relevant(d1)
>>> pprint.pprint(d1)
{'local': {'activities-events': {'count': 6,
                                 'life-skill-classes': {'count': 2},
                                 'outdoor-adventures': {'count': 4}},
           'count': 7}}

>>> d2 = {'local': {'count': 11, 'dining-and-nightlife': {'count': 4, 'bar-clubs': {'count': 4}}, 'activities-events': {'count': 6, 'outdoor-adventures': {'count': 4}, 'life-skill-classes': {'count': 2}}}}
>>> keep_most_relevant(d2)
>>> pprint.pprint(d2)
{'local': {'activities-events': {'count': 6,
                                 'life-skill-classes': {'count': 2},
                                 'outdoor-adventures': {'count': 4}},
           'count': 11,
           'dining-and-nightlife': {'bar-clubs': {'count': 4}, 'count': 4}}}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you update your question with the expected output?

Comment: see q count changes from 11 to 10

Answer (score 0):

```
def matches(match, cutoff):
    total = float(match['count'])

    for k in match:
        if k == 'count':
            continue

        score = match[k]['count'] / total

        if score >= cutoff:
            yield (k, score)

            m = list(matches(match[k], cutoff))
            if m: yield max(m, key=lambda (c, s): s)

def best_matches(d, cutoff):
    for k in d:
        for m in matches(d[k], cutoff):
            yield m
```

#### Test 1

```
>>> d = {'local': {'count': 7,
    'dining-and-nightlife': {'count': 1,
        'bar-clubs': {'count': 1}
    },
    'activities-events': {'count': 6,
        'outdoor-adventures': {'count': 4},
        'life-skill-classes': {'count': 2}
    }
}}
>>> print list(best_matches(d, 0.3))
[('activities-events', 0.8571428571428571), ('outdoor-adventures', 0.66666666666666663)]
```

#### Test 2

```
>>> d = {'local': {'count': 11,
    'dining-and-nightlife': {'count': 4,
        'bar-clubs': {'count': 4}
    },
    'activities-events': {'count': 6,
        'outdoor-adventures': {'count': 4},
        'life-skill-classes': {'count': 2}
    }
}}
>>> print list(best_matches(d, 0.3))
[('dining-and-nightlife', 0.36363636363636365), ('bar-clubs', 1.0), ('activities-events', 0.54545454545454541), ('outdoor-adventures', 0.66666666666666663)]
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The only issue is the output scores are relevant to their category i.e. in test 2 bar-clubs is 1.0 could I make it 0.36666.. Also I only need the lower level categories returned as matches i.e. bars-clubs, our-door adventures